# How can I reset form after save?

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

I am doing a product insert form in PrimeFaces dialog. My bean's scope is session. I can insert a product, but when I try to insert another product, the form has previous product's information. I want to reset form. I tried `UIInput` but it doesnt work. How can I clear the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new product after saving it and make sure that you're ajax-updating the form after save.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{productController.product.name}" />
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{productController.product.description}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productController.product.category}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{applicationData.categories}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{productController.save}" update="@form" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void save() {
    productService.save(product);
    product = new Product();
}
```

By the way, that kind of bean really doesn't belong in the session scope. Put it in the view scope.

Comment: but it depends scope. when I put in the view scope after create a new product , it's work but in the Session scope previous information is coming

Comment: Yes, when you're using view scope, then you can indeed also just return anything else than `null` or `void` (e.g. an empty string `""`), then the view will be recreated with all properties set to default. Isn't that exactly what you're looking for, then? Why sticking to session scope then?

Comment: Session bean isnt necessary but I should pass different page with navigation when I use in the view scope I get an error.But I turned to view scope. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. As to parameter-passing, use `h:link` and `f:viewParam`.